# Why we can not define the solution of the differential equation beyond a particular $t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I was studying Ordinary Differential Equations, and my book was trying to explain the maximal interval of solution of a differential equation. If we consider this differential equation
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2 \\
\text{with initial condition}~x(0)= a,~~~a \gt 0
$$
Then, the solution to this equation is
$$
x(t) = \frac{1}{ a^{-1} - t}$$
Now, if $t$ starts to increase from $0$ the denominator will decrease and consequently $x(t)$ will increase, when $t =a^{-1}$ the denominator is $0$ and $x(t) = + \infty$. As we let $t$ to decrease from $0$, our denominator will increase and finally when $t = -\infty$, $x(t) = 0$. So, the solution of the differential equation is defined on the interval $(-\infty, a^{-1})$. But the problem comes when the book makes this statement

> but there is no way to define the solution that extends further into the future beyond $t=a^{-1}$.

Why the function is not defined for $t \gt a^{-1}$? There is a discontinuity at $t=a^{-1}$ but beyond that the function is *nice*, why the solution is not defined after $t = a^{-1}$?

If compare $x(t)$ with some other simple functions like, for example, $f(x) = \frac{1}{2-x}$, $f(x)$ is well defined after $x = 2$, and here we have its graph:

[image].

Why the book says that beyond $t=a^{-1}$ the solution is not defined?

Comment: Hey, why don't you buy a new book? ;-) Just kidding! I think it is puzzling too. Maybe the writer had something physical in mind, for example that initial solution must be in the correct side of discontinuity. If you take $x(0)=2$ then for example only positive $x$ are allowed. Those $t>2$ can never reach your initial point.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069879/why-is-it-differential-equations-exist-on-an-interval-instead-of-a-domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, it depends on what we mean by a "solution", and what is meant by "extending" a solution. What you define as a solution of an initial value problem is somewhat a matter of taste, but here's a common approach.

For a first order initial value problem
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x,t)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ x(t_0)=x_0
$$
we may *define* a solution as a function $x:I\to\mathbb{R}$ where $I=(t_\min,t_\max)$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ containing $t_0$, which satisfies the initial condition and satisfies the differential equation wherever it is defined.

Why do we demand that solutions be defined on an open interval, and not some other domain? There are many reasons; one is that we would like solutions to be unique. Your IVP gives an example of what can go wrong if we don't do this: we could define $x(t)=(a^{-1}-t)^{-1}$ for $t\neq 0$, which satisfies the IVP. We could just as easily, however, define
$$
x(t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{a^{-1}-t} & t<a^{-1} \\
\frac{1}{b^{-1}-t} & t>a^{-1}
\end{cases}
$$
for any $b\ge a$. This is just as much a "solution" as the first choice, and so there are infinitely many distinct "solutions" in this sense. If we consider even more disconnected domains all kinds of different functions will be possible "solutions". This happens in general if we allow disconnected domains.

Of course, even by requiring solutions be defined on an open interval, there is still some redundancy, since we may always restrict to a smaller interval still containing the initial condition and obtain a new solution. If we want to define a solution which can be unique, we can look for the "largest possible" interval. To this end, given a solution $x:I\to\mathbb{R}$, we say another solution $y:I'\to\mathbb{R}$ is an *extension* of $x$ if $I\subset I'$ (that is, $I'$ contains $I$ and is strictly larger that $I$) and $x$ and $y$ agree on $I$. A *maximally extended solution* is one which has no extensions. Maximally extended solutions don't always exist (and they aren't always unique), but they do exist (and are unique) in many cases, such as when $f$ is sufficiently smooth.

In the sense defined above, the solution given by the text for your IVP $x:(-\infty,a^{-1})\to\mathbb{R}$ is maximally extended. We cannot choose a larger interval $(-\infty,c)$ with $c>a^{-1}$, since the function defined on that interval would fail to be differentiable at $a^{-1}$, and thus not satisfy the differential equation on its domain.

Comment: You should perhaps explicitly include that "satisfies the differential equation" implies that the function is continuous and differentiable on the interval, as OP said to extend the solution discontinuously.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Perhaps I wasn't explicit about it, but for $x$ to satisfy the differential equation on its domain certainly requires both sides of that equation be well defined, and thus that $x$ be differentiable on its domain. OP's "extension" is continuous on its domain, but its domain is disconnected.

Comment: It's a very good answer, thank you for that. So, the gist is that the domain of the solution must be "continuous" (I don't know if that's a misleading term)?

Comment: I think "g" is being omitted in the 4th para.

Comment: The appropriate term would be "connected". It's not so much that the domain *must* be connected, but that if we allow disconnected domains, we would have to deal with a infinite multitude of "solutions", which are, for the most part, not useful or interesting.